# Why is function undefined after the proper interface passing?

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript. AN example is from Frank Zametti's book

```
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  getGreeting(lastName:string) : string
};

const person = {
    firstName : "Frank",
    getGreeting(lastName: string) {
      return `Hello, ${this.firstName} ${lastName}`;
    }
};

function greet(person: IPerson) {
    (person.getGreeting("Zammetti"));
  }

console.log(greet(person));
```

I run first

```
tsc -t ES2017 p2.ts
```

and after that

```
node p2.js
```

undefined

Why? I just get rid of alert

```
function greet(person: IPerson) {
  alert(person.getGreeting("Zammetti"));
}
```

What does the alert stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imo if this is your real code you forgot about return in the `greet` implementation:

```js
function greet(person: IPerson) {
  return (person.getGreeting("Zammetti"));
}
```

so basically if a function does not return anything in fact in javascript-world it returns `undefined`, and that's why calling a `console.log(greet(...))` acted that way

and answering your second question:

`alert` was working by the same reason as `console.log` was not

`alert` is a part of `Web API` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert (one of earliest things in this language I believe, that's why it is so simple and exists in global scope)

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling type of persion to IPersion, and you are not returning anything from person object method hence undefined is returned.

```js
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
  getGreeting(lastName:string) : string
};

const person:IPerson = {
    firstName : "Frank",
    getGreeting(lastName: string) {
      return `Hello, ${this.firstName} ${lastName}`;
    }
};

function greet(person: IPerson) {
    return person.getGreeting("Zammetti");
}

console.log(greet(person));
```